# How to pass Data in Route State React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass data in Route State from link.
I want to open Contact Detail Page. My code is

```
import React from 'react'
import Me from "../images/blank-profile-picture-973460__340.webp"
import {Link,useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"
const Contactlists = (props) => {
const Contact =props.Contact;;
const Deleteitem=(ID)=>{
props.deletehandler(ID);
}

  return (
    <div className='ui called list' style={{marginTop:"50px"}}> 
  <h2>Contact List</h2>
<Link to="/add">
<button className='ui button blue right'>Add Contact</button>
</Link>
 {
  Contact.map((curlElem)=>{
return(
  <div className='item' key={curlElem.id}>
  <img src={Me} className='ui avatar image' alt="user"/>
<div className='ui content'>
<Link to={`/contactdetail/${curlElem.id}`} state={{ Contact:Contact }}>

<div className='header'>{curlElem.name}</div>
<div>{curlElem.email}</div>
{/* <button>{curlElem.name}</button> */}
</Link>
    </div>
<span><i className='trash alternate outline icon' style={{color:"red",marginLeft:"7px"}}
onClick={()=>Deleteitem(curlElem.id)}
key={curlElem.id}
></i></span>
        </div>
);
  })
 }
 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Contactlists
```

here is my route

```
<Route path="/contactdetail/:id" element={<ContactDetail  />}/>
```

here is the component where i am accessing it
but it show blank page i tried many different methods but insane

```
import React from 'react'
import me from "../images/me3.jpg"
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom"
const ContactDetail = () => {
  const location=useLocation();
  const Contact=location.state?.Contact;
  console.log(Contact)
  // console.log(props.detailcontact);
  // const{id,name,email}=props.detailcontact;
  return (
   <div className='main'>
    <div className='ui card centered'>
      <div className='image'>
<img src={me} alt="me"/>
      </div>
<div className='content'>
<div className='header'>Name:{Contact.name}</div>
<div className='discription'>Email:{Contact.email}</div>
</div>
    </div>

   </div>
  )
}

export default ContactDetail
```

here is data i am receiving in Console Log

```
0: {name: 'kamran', email: 'kamranalizx491gmail.com', id: '4a2f1073-cf0b-47c7-bca4-b4915c4933a5'}
1: {name: 'Techistic Kami', email: 'alializx414@gmail.com', id: 'b597cb0a-3355-45ab-9ac7-1c05c0b8cdb0'}
2: {id: '54b94038-8c3c-4ef7-b330-3fd2dcfd081d', name: 'kam', email: 'kamizx989@gmail.com'}
3: {id: '2658f40d-1f9d-42d7-b766-ab00afd47a91', name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491gmail.com'}
4: {id: '7d1f4a6c-0e88-4d90-9f23-5bd77c4f3fe4', name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com'}
5: {id: '949f3dfc-7623-48d8-8ebc-2d3e39af6eaa', name: 'kamran', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com'}
6: {name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com', id: '2abbc0d6-bd40-49be-903f-3135aaa8d4a5'}
7: {name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com', id: 'ae8b4841-7418-4ea8-a20f-0d300a5eb850'}
8: {name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com', id: 'e4fe382f-7e35-49eb-9c48-f5dd667fd3bf'}
9: {name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com', id: '65a2f9f7-9031-4b52-9def-2b65f501ea75'}
10: {id: '61855c5a-0821-49e5-966b-509883b0a6db', name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com'}
11: {id: '282a1f6b-d0c8-4fde-bb60-0abd3cbd5ef6', name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com'}
12: {id: '80823775-e4bc-4d33-bc59-4270ba423edd', name: 'Kamran Ali', email: 'kamranalizx491@gmail.com'}
13: {id: '5b66e91c-0c93-48df-820f-29a6493e3407', name: 'zain', email: 'Zain@gmaiol.com'}
length: 14
```

Now I have edit the code please and suggest me the best solution as I am new to react js and following tutorial from youtube but I am facing many problems as I do the same like instructor

Comment: What is the "Contact" that you are passing to <Link> component? Is it a js object or a TypeScript Object?

Comment: it is a object contains id,name,email

Comment: Please don't write in ALL CAPS. It's considered shouting and rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are sending ***all*** the data in the route state. In other words, the code is passing the entire array, the `id`, `name`, and `email` properties are undefined in this array.

A second issue is that that the `ContactDetail` doesn't handle rendering when the `location.state.Contact` is undefined. It assumes there's a defined object to destructure properties from.

## Solution

Either filter the array prior to sending it, or filter the passed state in the receiving component. In this case you likely meant to send the specific element value that is being mapped.

Example:

```
{Contact.map((curlElem) => {
  return(
    <div className='item' key={curlElem.id}>
      <img src={Me} className='ui avatar image' alt="user" />
      <div className='ui content'>
        <Link
          to={`/contactdetail/${curlElem.id}`}
          state={{ Contact: curlElem }} // <-- pass curlElem here!!
        >
          <div className='header'>{curlElem.name}</div>
          <div>{curlElem.email}</div>
        </Link>
        ...
```

Update `ContactDetail` to handle possibly undefined state.

```
const ContactDetail = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { Contact = {} } = state || {}; // <-- provide fallback value

  console.log(Contact);

  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <div className='ui card centered'>
        <div className='image'>
          <img src={me} alt="me"/>
        </div>
        <div className='content'>
          <div className='header'>Name:{Contact.name}</div>
          <div className='description'>Email:{Contact.email}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

React router's `Link` component takes a `state` prop where you can pass data to the component that should be rendered for your path, example:

```
<Link to="/your-path" state={{ data: data }}>
   Some text
</Link>
```

Then in your component, you can access this data using `useLocation` hook:

```
const location = useLocation();
const data = location.state?.data;
```

To be more specific with your case, you can pass the data in your `Link` like so:

```
<Link to={`/contactdetail/${curlElem.id}`} state={{ name: curlElem.name, email: curlElem.email, id: curlElem.id }}>
   Some text
</Link>
```

That way you can access the specific data you need in your component:

```
const location = useLocation();
const { name, email, id } = location.state;
```

Comment: Then How to display it ??

Comment: Following this example and assuming `data` is an object that contains `id`, `name` and `email`, you should be able to access it as usual: `data.name`, `data.id`, etc. It would be a good idea if you console log data just to be sure tho.

Comment: I tried this method but im getting all contacts in console log i just want the specific one whose id i am passing in link
that's why it is not displaying content by using this methid data.name etc

Comment: Is the data you want to pass via `Link` an array of objects? If that's the case then you can filter it. If you can please edit your question and include a console log of your data to have a better understanding of what you're working with.

Comment: I edited my answer, please check and let me know if it works.